# Doxygen duplicate documentation from @file and @defgroup

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I'm using Doxygen to document a project. In one file, I have a bunch of public functions that I want to put in a group. I do this as follows:

```
/**
    @file myFile.c
    @brief This is a file. It has stuff.
*/
/**
    @defgroup my_group Group with myFile.c stuff
    @{
*/

//CODE & STUFF WITH DOCUMENTATION

/**
   @}
*/
```

The issue is that the LaTeX output contains all of the documentation here twice; once in the "Module Documentation" section and again in the "File Documentation" section. This amounts to maybe 25 pages of purely duplicate stuff in my end PDF file (generated from LaTeX).

An ideal fix would be to have the File Documentation for myFile.c say "See @ref my_group" or something like that. Is there a way to accomplish this in Doxygen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptable solution found:

1. Create a Doxygen layout XML file and configure Doxygen to use it ([instructions](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html))
2. Open the XML file; find the `<group>` tag; comment out the `<detaileddescription>` and `<memberdef>` sections

This resulted in only the list of members being produced in the "Module Documentation," with hyperlinks to the full member documentation within the "File Documentation" section in the LaTeX/PDF output. The HTML output already functioned this way, so it was not significantly changed.